# How can I hide the sort bar of Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I have almost all other elements of Thunderbird hidden to create a minimal interface. I keep my mail sorted by date only so I do not need the sort bar.

Does the sort bar have a class name (like `.sortBar`) that I can easily hide with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

This [`userChrome.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css) works as of Thunderbird 31.1.1:

```css
vbox#threadContentArea > tree#threadTree > treecols:first-child {
    height:0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Notes:

1. Just using `display:none` doesn't work in this case; comments welcome if someone knowledgeable with XUL / moz CSS knows why. The rules above work around that, but leave an empty space of 8px height. Again, improvements welcome :)
2. To create such rules, use the DOM Inspector addon (install it from Thunderbird's "Extensions" screen), then inspect the XUL tree of Thunderbird (`File > Inspect Chrome Document`), and try to build a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) of what you want to modify.